# Не применяются стили для текста маркера при выхода маркера из кластера

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Помогите решить проблему.
Для маркера повесил текст в div, при изменении масштаба карты меняется стиль текста. При масштабирование и изменения положения карты работает нормально, но при выходе маркера из кластера для того маркера который вышел из кластера не применяться стиль пока не изменить положение карты(просто сдвинуть) или еще раз увеличить масштаб.
Ниже привожу листинг кода который весит на масштабе

```
////////////////////////////////////////////
    myMap.events.add('boundschange', function (event) {
        zooom=myMap.getZoom();
        if(zooom>=18){
            objectManager.objects.options.set('preset',objectIconMin);
            $('.nameCompany').css({"display":"inline-block"});
            $('.priceBanner').css({"font-size":"34px","color":"#078985","margin-left":"5px","margin-top":"20px","margin-right":"0px"});
        }else{
            objectManager.objects.options.set('preset',objectIconMax);
            $('.nameCompany').css({"display":"none"});
            $('.priceBanner').css({"font-size":"14px","color":"#fff","margin-right":"70px","margin-top":"30px"});
        }
    });
///////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день.
В момент, когда вы вызываете $('.nameCompany') макеты меток могут быть еще не созданы на странице (не быть добавлены в DOM). Можно было бы применять стили с задержкой, но это кажется не самый оптимальный путь.
Кажется, что правильным правильным способом было бы сделать собственный макет метки средствами API. В макете использовалась бы некоторая опция, которая как раз и задавалась бы при смене уровня масштаба.

Comment: Спасибо большое, совет помог)

Comment: Дмитрий, если совет помог, то не плохо было бы принять ответ и не оставлять без внимания человека, который не оставил без внимания тебя... Принять ответ - это нажать на серую галочку с лева от  ответа и она станет зеленой...